# ostringstreamで扱ったtxtファイルの文字化け

Tags: c++, gcc, wsl

注：CompanyはFileクラスから継承。set_written_elementでwriteに文字列を渡し、表示させる。
macでは問題ないが、windows10のwslではtxtファイルが文字化けを起こします。
いったい何が悪いのでしょうか？

gccのバージョンはgcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6) 5.4.0 20160609でした。
txtファイルをvimで見ると `illegal byte in line` となっており、文字コードをもとのutf-8からshift-jis, euc-jpに直しても変わらなかったため、質問させていただきました。

```
int main(){
  Company company_test;
  char path[]="company_test.txt";
  company_test.input_path(path);
  company_test.show();
  company_test.write(company_test.set_written_element());
  cout << company_test.set_written_element() << endl; //winだとset_written_elementがおかしい
  company_test.show();
  return 0;
}

void File::write(const char* text){
  int line_number;
  line_number=Line_Count(output_path());
  ofstream fd(output_path(),ios::app);
  fd << line_number << " " << text << "\n";
  fd.close();
}

const char* Company::set_written_element(){
  const char* written_element;
  string buffer;
  string tmp;
  ostringstream ret_char;
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<=2;i++){
    switch(i){
      case 0:
        cout << "勤務先を入力してください。" << endl;
        cin >> buffer;
        ret_char << setw(25) << left << buffer;
        buffer.clear();
        break;

      case 1:
        cout << "時給を入力してください。" << endl;
        cin >> buffer;
        ret_char << setw(10) << left << buffer;
        buffer.clear();
        break;

      case 2:
        cout << "備考を入力してください。" << endl;
        cin >> buffer;
        ret_char << setw(50) << left << buffer;
        buffer.clear();
        break;
    }
  }
  tmp = ret_char.str();
  written_element = tmp.c_str();
  return written_element;
}
```

Comment: 「文字化け」では第三者には伝わりません。どのような操作、結果をもって文字化けと判断したのかを明確にしてください。

Comment: ご意見ありがとうございます。今後の説明の際参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> const char* Company::set_written_element(){
>   const char* written_element;
>   string buffer;
>   string tmp;
> ~~
>   written_element = tmp.c_str();
>   return written_element;
> }
> ```

少なくとも`return`する直前に`string tmp`のデストラクターが実行され`tmp`の指していた文字列のメモリは解放されます。そのため、`Company::set_written_element()`が返す文字列は不正なアドレスを指していることになります。素直に`string`を返すべきです。

```
string Company::set_written_element(){
  string buffer;
  string tmp;
~~
  return tmp;
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。stringオブジェクトtmpはset_written_element()内で宣言されているのにｔｍｐを返したらこれも不正なアドレスになってしまうと思ったのですが、このように書くとそうはならないのでしょうか？

Comment: `return`で返したオブジェクトは呼び出し元にコピーされます。

Comment: 初歩的な質問に丁寧に回答していただきありがとうございました。もう一度やり直してみます。